# How do i style with svelte headless UI

Tags: svelte, headless-ui

### headless-UI: https://svelte-headlessui.goss.io/docs/

So i just can't figure out how i can style a PopoverButton i have tried to interpret the docs but i was unable to get anywhere so if someone is able to provide some guidance then i that would be very helpful!

In a video i've seen that you can simply assign it to a class but that does not seem to be the case since the CSS selector remains unused.

Comment: [Does that help](https://svelte-headlessui.goss.io/docs/popover#styling)?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour this is what i've read along with the styling docs but i still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Vimesh Style](https://github.com/vimeshjs/vimesh-style). It allows you using Tailwind CSS at runtime. It monitors the class attribute of every element. If there are Tailwind CSS, it will inject the CSS definition into the page.